# getting error from mysqli_fetch_array

Tags: mysql, sql

My query line is:

```
SELECT TR.*, 
       PL.*, DE.*, 
       ( DE.power + DE.stamina + DE.violence + DE.speed + DE.shooting + DE.scoring + DE.pass + DE.ball_control + DE.talent ) AS TPOWER,
       strftime('%Y-%d-%m', DE.age, 'unixepoch') AS age 
       FROM `transfers` TR JOIN `players` PL ON TR.player_id=PL.id 
       JOIN `playerdetails` DE ON TR.player_id=DE.player_id
       WHERE PL.position = 'MD' AND ( age >= '20' AND age <= '24' ) 
       AND PL.firstname = 'a' AND PL.lastname = 'b' AND TPOWER >= '1' 
       AND TPOWER <= '5' AND TR.price >= '20' AND TR.price <= '50'
       ORDER BY age DESC
```

What's wrong with this query?

An error occurred:

```
Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in E:\EasyPHP-Devserver-16.1\eds-www\classes\DB.php on line 15
```

Comment: is mysql complaining or is it not doing what you want?

Comment: @P.Salmon I just get an Error "Warning", You can see the update.

Comment: Can you connect to the database through client software and execute the same query to see if the syntax is correct? Or, use the `mysli_error()` function to get the error reported when executing the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL doesn't have a function called `strftime()`.  You might want `date_format()` instead:

```
SELECT . . .
       date_format(de.age, '%Y-%d-%m') AS age
```

However, that seems like a strange way to express the age (which is usually an integer, number, or interval).

Your query could have other errors as well.  You should check the error messages that are returned.

Comment: `De.age` is a timestamp like 1384554616161 , Does the function do it for me to calculate a person's age like 19?

Comment: @johnmartel . . . `from_unixtime()` (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime).